# How to return top 10 results from a table based on a condition on one of the columns on the table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a huge table in excel which shows numbers for a specific list of companies. The numbers are in a column alongside the name of the companies. I need to get the top 10 (based on the numbers) users for each company.

Sample as follows:

[image]

So I need to build out a list with the top 10 users for each company based on the number value

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could sort by Company then Number (desc). Then a new column (column D) would have this formula in cell D2: =IF(A2<>A1,1,D1+1)    Drag it down, then copy everything and paste as special values elsewhere, and remove everything over 10. Manual, but works.

Comment: How to display in new Table? In you filter top 10 by Power Query directly..

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 solution:

- Make the data table a **Table**

  - I **NAME**'d it `Table2`
- Define Name:  `topN` (to make the number of users to return a variable)

*Since you only provide three/four instances of each Company, I chose `topN` refers to `E2 => 2`, but you can just change that to `10` for your real data*

[image]

Formulas:

```
G2: =UNIQUE(Table2[Company])
H2: =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Table2[[User]:[Number]],G2=Table2[Company]),2,-1),SEQUENCE(topN),1))
```

*Select `H2` and fill down as far as needed*

Algorithm:

- Filter the Table to return columns 1 and 3 if it matches the Company name in column G
- Sort that filtered table by the Number column descending
- Return the `topN` rows from that table